# I have installed the font in my windows7 and embed in dreamweaver

Tags: css

Here is the link: http://chinmayaeducationcell.com/home.php  look the header content **Central Chinmaya Mission Trust Education Cell** for this  I have used Pristina font,please check the url. Is the font type is applied for this and also I have downloaded the font and installed kept in font folder, but i have not called in my coding.kindly check this?t

```
<h3 id="cent">Central Chinmaya Mission Trust Education Cell</h3>

In css:
    #cent{
    width:642px;
    height:auto;
    color:#E58752;
    float:left; 
    font-family:Pristina;
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight:bolder;
}
@font-face
{
font-family:Pristina;
src:url('./font/Pristina.ttf');
}
```

Comment: what is it that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In your website directory make a font folder and insert the font file into this folder. Once you have done this return to your CSS sheet and import the font into your stylesheet using the @font-face

Then as you have set font-family it should display the font correctly

Comment: Thanks please check the question I have updated the answer by your suggestion, check now is the font type is applied I could not trigger out. check with same link

Comment: Please add font-face commands at the very beginning of your stylesheet. CSS performs operations in the same order as they are inserted into the stylesheet.   You are establishing a font after it has been called at the moment

Comment: Also it seems you have placed fonts folder in root directory your src should read as follows src: url('../fonts/pristina.ttf');

Comment: I have done check it now,is it applied? one more query for another tag like welcome to our site I want to use different font  face for that what I have do here id is #cent, like this shall i want to create #welcome and has to call like this

Comment: Yes it is displaying correctly now. You may need to clear your browser cache to see it for yourself.

Comment: For your welcome message create a new heading with an id="welcome-msg" . in your css add the other font-face at start of css stylesheet and then in css #welcome-msg set font family to new font face

Comment: can you explain me where the does the relationship happening here because i have use #cent{float:left; font-family:Pristina;} where does the font face plays here?

Comment: So in your php page where you would like to add this welcome message create new heading eg. <h1 id=welcome-msg">Welcome to our site</h1> . Now in your directory font folder add new font you want then in css use @font-face to register new font. Then after that scroll to bottom add new css rule #welcome-msg {font-family: "insert-font-name"}